# Update elements in an ArrayList using a HashMap that keeps track of the indexes

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I'm implementing a queue class in which the elements (implemented using an ArrayList) should be updatable and I have a HashMap instance variable to keep track of their indexes, so the function won't have to iterate through the array looking for the object to be replaced.

I'm trying to do it like this:

```
public void update(T oldElement, T newElement) {
    int index = map.get(oldElement);
    map.put(newElement, index);
    elements.set(index, newElement);
}
```

The parameter oldElement is a reference to an object that is sure to be equal to the element that's going to be replaced, but I realize that they still are separate objects and oldElement cannot be found in my HashMap, because it isn't a key there. I really can't think of any ideas around this and any help would be appreciated.

The HashMap looks like this:

```
private HashMap<T, Integer> map = new HashMap<T, Integer>();
```

Edit: the method updade is called by code outside of the class.

---

#### Solved

It was due to a bug in my remove() method. I didn't realize HashMap actually uses the objects' hashes.

Comment: Whats wrong with removing index/oldElement from your map and adding index/newElement afterwards?

Comment: You need insert/remove methods, which also update your map to keep it consistent to your array.

Comment: When you say "sure to be equal", have you actually implemented your own equals and hashCode methods?

Comment: Steve: I have. Everyone: It was a bug in the remove() method that caused the error, I just thought it was because they were distinct objects. I didn't realize HashMap actually uses the objects's hashes when comparing. :/ I need sleep. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a hash function that, instead of storing the actual key, stores the hash, that is guaranteed to be equal if the two key values are equal. This is equivalent to implementing `.equals()` and `.hashCode()` in the key class, but if you cannot do that then this is a possible alternative:

```
protected int calculateHash(T key) {
  // Your hash calculation is done here, the hash function must guarantee
  // that the hash value is equal when feed equal keys, for example
  // suppose that the key object contains a getName() method:
  return getName().hashCode();
}
```

And use the method to access the map, rather than the element value itself:

```
map.put(calculateHash(newElement), index);
```

and:

```
map.get(calculateHash(element));
```

Note that you do not need to update the map when the key object changes (as long as it produces the same hash code as the old one), you need to update the map only when the index changes.

If you are able to implement `.hashCode()` and `.equals()` in the `T` class, this is all unnecessary. Eclipse or other IDEs can automatically generate these methods for you. Implementing `.hashCode()` and `.equals()` is a best practice for all classes dealing with collections, especially if you're using `Set`s and `Map`s.

Comment: Thank you! It turns out I didn't really know the purpose of the hash method, but it was already implemented. The error was due to a bug in another method.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use `LinkedHashMap`, which guarantees order, and also makes it possible to delete/get in O(1).

You may also simply use `LinkedHashSet`, if you only want to store the objects themselves, and no ancillary accounting information in companion objects.

Both solutions (and your solution too, by the way), as @EmirCalabuch pointed out, require that the same object does not get entered into the queue twice, and that the objects have correctly implemented equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: This would be my advice too, but only if the object classes implement `.hashCode()` and `.equals()`, otherwise it would not work. Also, this solution imposes a uniqueness constraint on objects, whereas a normal list does not. This is not a criticism to the answer, just noting that it requires the equality methods as well.

Comment: It's a priority queue, so the ordering is different. Anyway, I found the error in another method, I just wrongfully assumed that it was due to the objects being distinct (I actually had the hashCode and equals methods implemented). Well, now I know how hash tables work. Thank you guys for your time!